# Extract a string between two words, with multiple patterns

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a series of strings like "the appointment of XX as head", "appoints YY as head" (included in a data frame labelled "df" in a column labelled "title")

I want to extract the names XX, XY enclosed between the two different expressions.

I'm currently using the following:

```
df$name <- df$title %>% 
  str_extract(regex(pattern = "(?<=Appointment of).*(?= as)", ignore_case=TRUE))
```

However, that works with only one of the two possible patterns.

```
df$name <- df$title %>% 
  str_extract(regex(pattern = "(?<=Appointment of).*(?= as)"|"(?<=joins).*(?= as)", ignore_case=TRUE))
```

which of course does not work.
How can I create multiple patterns to feed into str_extract?

Happy to provide further details if needed!

Thanks a lot

Comment: `"(?<=Appointment of).*?(?= as)|(?<=joins).*?(?= as)"`? Or `"(?<=Appointment of|joins).*?(?= as)"`?

Comment: Hi Wiktor, that's brilliant and I should have imagined that already! It works!

Comment: I'd suggest updating the question with testing data and expected results.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, it works...I just had an empty space too much when I was trying the code, but now it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strapply can do it without using zero width constructs.  Only the second capture group is returned.

```
library(gsubfn)

x <- c("the appointment of XX as head", "appoints YY as head") # input
strapply(x, "(appointment of|appoints) (.*?) as head", ~ ..2, simplify = TRUE)
## [1] "XX" "YY"
```

or use (?:...) to specify that the first parenthesized portion is not to be a capture group:

```
strapply(x, "(?:appointment of|appoints) (.*?) as head", simplify = TRUE)
## [1] "XX" "YY"
```

### Base R

In base R it could be done with sub if every component of x matches

```
sub(".*(appointment of|appoints) (.*?) as head.*", "\\2", x)
## [1] "XX" "YY"
```

or strcapture if not

```
proto <- data.frame(dummy = character(0), value = character(0))
strcapture("(appointment of|appoints) (.*?) as head", x, proto)[, 2]
## [1] "XX" "YY"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
df$name <- df$title %>% 
  str_extract(regex(pattern = "(?<=\\bAppointment of\\s|\\bjoins\\s).*?(?=\\s+as\\b)", ignore_case=TRUE))
```

*Details*:

- `(?<=` - start of a positive lookbehind

  - `\bAppointment of\s`  - a word boundary (`\b`), `Appointment of`, and then a whitespace char (`\s`)
- `|` - or

  - `\bjoins\s` - a whole word `joins` and a whitespace
- `)` - end of the lookbehind
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars
- `(?=\s+as\b)` - a positive lookahead that requires one or more whitespaces, `as` and a word boundary immediately to the right of the current location.

Note that in `stringr`, the lookbehind patterns are not strictly fixed-width, you can use

```r
"(?<=\\bAppointment of\\s{1,100}|\\bjoins\\s{1,100}).*?(?=\\s+as\\b)"
```

where `\s{1,100}` can match one to a hundred whitespace chars.

Comment: Thank you very much - not only it works, but I understood a it better the regex syntax! Very much appreciated